# iOS 13 Remove Observer in UICollectionViewCell custom Class

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nsnotificationcenter

Hi everyone I need to add 2 observers in my `UICollectionViewCell` Custom Class.
I implemented the two observers in this way

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
     super.init(frame: frame)

     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(disablePreviousMinutes), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)

     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(enableMinute), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationIdentifier2"), object: nil)
}
```

Now I would like to know how I can remove observers from my `UICollectionViewCell` class

I tried calling `override func willMove(toWindow newWindow: UIWindow?)` But in this way all the inserted functions are repeated for all the cells

What is the best way to remove an observer from a `UICollectionViewCell` custom class?

Comment: How about removing the observer in deinit? But if I remember correctly, you don’t even need to remove observers since iOS 10 or so

Comment: @JoRa I tried to insert a print in deinit but it is not called when I close the view that contains the collection view so I thought there are problems

Comment: Deinitialization is only called when no references to that object are active anymore. In your example, it could mean that iOS internally holds a reference even when your specific view goes out of bounds. This is not necessarily a problem, sometimes it’s a desired effect to reduce loading times in future. If you really do want to manually remove the observer, I would go with deinit

Comment: @JoRa at the moment I was reading the apple documentation where it says it is the target of my app and iOS9 or later not necessary to remove the observers ... as you said! So is it better to leave the observers as they are now without removing them? Does this approach apply to all observers? leaving observers without removing them is a safe way then?

Comment: Yes, that‘s exactly what I meant. Works for all observers of NotificationCenter. A welcome time saver :)

Comment: @JoRa Yes, really! useless searches for safe ways to remove the observers .. in this way everything is much faster !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just giving a short write-up so you can mark this question as solved.

As you found out, since iOS 9 you don’t need to manually remove observers from NotificationCenter. they are automatically removed.

If you still want to remove them, you can safely do so in deinit()